# bluez: scan and connect in parallel

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, hci

what I want to achieve in a test setup is:

running:

```
hcitool -i hci0 lescan --duplicates --passive
```

on one shell

and in parallel connect on another via

```
hcitool -i hci0 lecc <BTADDR>
```

The moment I issue the connect command the scan process exits.

Why is that? I thought choosing to scan `--passive` will allow a scan output while managing a connection?

Best,

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on kernel 3.2 and above use gatttool or bluetoothctl for LE connections. hcitool is deprecated and you should not be using them anymore. Compile and install latest bluez and use gatttool for LE connections. If your LE device is in the vicinity, you should be able to connect, read and write using gatttool directly:

say, your local BT adapter is hci0 and the remote device BD_ADDR is 12:22:33:44:55:66 then:

```
gatttool -i hci0 -b 12:22:33:44:55:66 -I
[12:22:33:44:55:66][LE]>connect
Attempting to connect to 12:22:33:44:55:66
Connection successful
[12:22:33:44:55:66][LE]>characteristics
```

Read manual and help to know more about gattool.